# Understanding Merge and Sort Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

So I'm trying to understand this simple merge and sort algorithm in python. Here's the code:

```
def merge(left, right, lt):
    """Assumes left and right are sorted lists.

    lt defines an ordering on the elements of the lists.
    Returns a new sorted(by lt) list containing the same elements
    as (left + right) would contain.

    """
    result = []
    i,j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
       if lt(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
        while (i < len(left)):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        while (j < len(right)):
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    return result

def sort(L, lt = lambda x,y: x < y):
    """Returns a new sorted list containing the same elements as L"""
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = int(len(L)/2)
        left = sort(L[:middle], lt)
        right = sort(L[middle:], lt)
        print left, right
        return merge(left, right, lt)
```

I get what it's trying to do, and I understand all of the code in the merge function and have a basic understanding of the sort function.

What I don't understand is how the "else" portion of the sort function actually works. It seems like it keeps recursively calling the sort function to assign smaller and smaller split lists to the left and right variables. But since it is assigning new lists to "left" and "right" on every call to the recursive function, won't the end result just be the smallest versions of left and right?

How does the merge function, which seems to lie outside of the recursion, know that it needs to merge every single split list created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort()` is recursive, but up to a point. The `if` condition will break the recursion once the length of the `list` is less than two (or equal to one):

```
if len(L) < 2:
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) actually has a nice animation that shows how Merge sort works:

[image]

Basically, `merge()` combines two sorted lists and returns a single *sorted* list. `sort()` recursively breaks up your list into pairs and sorts the pairs one step at a time, merging two sorted pairs to form a larger sorted list at every step in the recursion. Just watch the animation. It's better at explaining than I am.

Comment: I watched that entire animation.

Comment: Okay, so now I get that at the end of the function, merge is called to sort the pair. But how does the function continue after that to keep sorting the pairs, as shown in the image above? It seems like the function would simply end after merge is returned.

Comment: You have to wrap your head around recursion because you're calling `sort` from within `sort`. Past the first split of the large list, all those small steps are being performed in the recursion as each of those larger lists is being split in half and worked on. Try manually unraveling the recursion for a trivial list `[2, 1]` and then `[2, 3, 1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should draw out the call stack and see what happens.

When the `else` clause calls the `sort` functions again, the function doesn't exit there. Every call ends in one of the `return` statements.

So you're correct that initially the calls to `sort` are passed in smaller and smaller lists, but once the length becomes less than 2, 'sort' returns the list itself. Then the call returns to where it was and calls `print` and finally `merge`.

Try using a small list and write down every call. You'll see that eventually `merge` does get called on small lists which have been sorted (since they're so short).